# Can I isolate amplify-authenticator styles?

Tags: css, angular, aws-amplify

In order to have appropriate styles applied to the `<amplify-authenticator>` component, I followed the instructions here : https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1870

This means installing @aws-amplify/ui and importing stylesheets.

However, these stylesheets contain unspecified selectors, which change elements like span and h3. I don't want the authenticator's styles to dictate my entire application's styles (or vice versa).

Is there a way to restrict these styles to only apply to a certain component tree?

ViewEncapsulation seems like the answer, but it doesn't seem to provide the right restriction, since I am using an imported component that I don't control.

Using Angular 7.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but I managed to do it by adding this to the component stylesheet:

```css
::ng-deep {
  @import '~@aws-amplify/ui/src/Theme';
  @import '~@aws-amplify/ui/src/Angular';
  @import '~@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style';
}
```

Note, this only works when using Angular and Sass/SCSS for now. From what I understand, support for deep selectors is going away soon anyway

Comment: I am very much looking forward to see a real solution from AWS-side. This works for now, thank you for the solution @Chris